# Angular2 parent menu should be active while selecting child menu

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm new to Angular2, I have one problem, I have a sidebar if I select one menu list page will open and if I select role it will redirect to another page till this its working fine, but in child page, the parent menu is not active how to make it as active.
 Please help me to find the solution.

```js
app.routing.ts:
 {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
           
            { path: 'sp-list', loadChildren: './sp-list/sp-list.module#SpListModule'},
              { path: 'sp-details', loadChildren: './sp-list/sp-list.module#SpListModule'},
              ]}
```

```html
app-routing.html:
 <a [routerLink]="['/sp-list','/sp-details']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i>&nbsp;Page
        </a>
     //// I tired like this,its not working
```

Comment: can you pls create a plunker for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for my admin panel, I had one left panel subcomponent that was being used at the top level component and will be appearing on each sub-routes.

Here are screenshots for handling such menu and submenu auto selection. Html code as well as the left panel code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks